# Is it pythonic to put return after yield?

Tags: python, generator, yield

Consider the following code:

```
def some_gen():
    if some_condition:
        yield "Condition"
        return
    for ....:
        yield some_value
```

'return' after 'yield' hurts my eyes, is there a more "pythonic" way?
(I know I could use 'else', but I'd like to avoid unnecessary nesting)

It also might cause a bit of confusion during a code review, because empty return gives None

Comment: I don't see any problem with such `return`.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, if you need to quit a generator function early.

Comment: *"hurts my eyes"* - Why?

Comment: "Hurts my eyes" 'cause it looks like mixing yields with returns, and also empty return raises a doubt about yielding None, or so.
But if you say it's OK, it's probably OK. I just added a brief comment.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think a more pythonic way to do this is to put the if statement in another function. You are trying to use the function as a function and generator at the same time.

I would do something like this:

```py
def some_gen():
    for ...:
        yield some_value

def some_func():
    if some_condition:
        gen.close()
        return "value"
    return next(gen)

gen = some_gen()
```

Comment: It looks good at a glance, but I've got a tradeoff here: the generator is widely used already, and I have added the condition to it only recently. I don't want to loose the encapsulation

Comment: If the code is already used the way you're describing, then why do want to change it? It sounds like you just want another word for `return`.